# Repair Linux Mint (Cinnamon) after deleteing some files

Tags: linux-mint, data-recovery

Alright, so I did a very stupid thing the other day. I was building a python program in pycharm, and I wanted to see what the UI looked like in the terminal. So I tried to run the code, but I didn't work because python 2.7 was installed not python 3.5. So my brain at 2 am decided that It would delete python 2.7 and install python 3.5, but at the time I didn't realize that linux mint was dependant on python... so I removed it.

I don't know how much was deleted but it paused to ask me whether I preferred mdm or lightdm. I (with no real linux experience) panicked and decided that I would reboot, and hope in the reboot process that Linux mint would realize that packages were missing automatically download and restore them. Wrong, I just got stuck on the logo it the boot screen. Then I rebooted Linux mint recovery. Ran `aptitude -f`, it showed some packages recommended to install and I pressed <kbd>g</kbd> to install them. Then I ran `dpkg`. It installed a few. I tried to reboot into Linux Mint but it still wasn't working.

So after googling I ran across `debsums` and so I did what the forum told me to do and It fixed all my corrupted and missing files. Still wasn't working.
After googling more I ran into `aptitude --reinstall '-i'` (Which would reinstall all packages) but it requires aptitude v0.7.3 and I have v0.6.8.2. When I try to `apt-get install aptitude`, it claims that aptitude is already at the newest version.

As of right now when I reboot the Ubuntu 17.2 logo pops up instead of the Linux Mint, but the computer still boot-loops.

Can I fix this without losing my data? I would rather fix it than reinstall Linux Mint if possible.

Comment: Do you remember how exactly did you remove python? I mean with `python*` regex for example, for me to be able to simulate a few scenarios in a VM?

Comment: I did `apt-get remove python` I then typed the `Yes, do as I say!`

Comment: Not that this is particularly helpful, but hopefully you're learned the lesson that if you're not only asked if you're sure, but have to show _just_ how sure you are, you might want to make certain you're fully awake before telling the system you're really really surely sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is what happened in a VM to me when removing regex python*:

[image]

Since I can't figure out how to install all of it back in, it will be hard to put it together.

I will not poke you further, you have learned lesson the hard way. Maybe is someone able to fix it, but I doubt it will be faster than a clean install. That is why I post this.